# Train Chinese Segmenter with custom sources

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to train the Chines Segenter with new data and i produced a dictionary and a serialized treebank text file.

My problem is that i do not understand or find documentations about the difference between:

-sighanCorporaDict data

and

-trainFile train.txt

Can somebody help me out with this problem. My Chinese datasets are Buddhist ancient texts which makes it hard to replace ressources like -sighanCorporaDict?

All the best

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation here for training your own Chinese segmenter:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter-faq.html

`sighanCorporaDict` is a directory with resources the segmenter needs...this should be set to the `data` directory in the segmenter distribution

`trainFile` should be a list of sentences that have been properly segmented (words separated by space).

Comment: Unfortunately this page does not explain the parameters. I thought the parameter -serDictionary ist the list for the known words which I have to prepare in advance. What ist the difference between -serDictionary and -sighanCorporaDict which is basically a directory?

Comment: I was incorrect.  There is a data directory in the segmenter distribution.  You can download the folder here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml  ...within that downloaded folder there is a directory called data, and that is what you want to put for the sighanCorporaDict setting.  If you look through the code you'll see it trying to get resources from sighanCorporaDict+"dict/"...so mainly the code uses things like "data/dict/pku.non" and "data/dict/ctb.non", etc...

Comment: But why? What is the purpose of the directory?

Comment: The data directory contains a dict directory which has files the segmenter uses such as pku.non...I'm not sure what the files are for but they are resources for some of the features.  Somewhere in the training code, when it tries to evaluate feature values it loads that file and does something with it.

Comment: Just to clarify pku.non is not a list of known words, it is some supplementary resource for the training process.

Comment: Also for instance part of the training code uses "dict/char.ctb.list" which appears to be a list of characters.

Comment: As I train the segmenter with a treebank of the chinese buddhist canon I'am not shure if I should exchange those ressources to. What do you think? In some cases it could be different since it is an old instance of chinese language and contains some sanskrit characters. But if you think it does not have any influence to the accuracy of the model I could leave it as it is.

Comment: My advice would be to review the source code and see what resources are being used and then see what they are.  I think you will probably get better performance if you set these resources to match your specific problem.  Of course you could also experiment with leaving them alone and see if you are happy with the results.  Source code is here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP ... you should search for sighanCorporaDict ... I think you'll find a lot of the code in edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg

Comment: In the source i see a parameter sighanPostProcessing. If I set this to false, which is standard, would that be disable the usage of this resource?